# Acoustic training of Windows speech engine

Tags: c#, windows, speech

I have been working on improving the performance of my code that uses the Windows speech API specifically for some indispensable commands, for example open file, scroll up, scroll down etc.

Though most of the commands seem to be recognised well but **the code performs poorly when there are characters with similar pronunciation** like B, D, G, P. After some rigorous search I figured out that maybe we could **add semantics** to the grammar builder like given below, i.e. we may provide many ambiguous cases of B the same semantic value and similarly for D, but it may not be a great idea. Another way could be **acoustic training** by turning on the training mode by using `ISpRecognizer2::SetTrainingState` that switches in or out of the training mode.

```
Choices digits = new Choices();  
GrammarBuilder digitValues = new GrammarBuilder();  
SemanticResultValue temp = new SemanticResultValue("B", B);    
digits.Add(temp);    
digitValues.Append(temp);    

temp = new SemanticResultValue("Bee", B);     
digits.Add(temp);     
digitValues.Append(temp);      

temp = new SemanticResultValue("Ba", B);     
digits.Add(temp);    
digitValues.Append(temp);
```

Please suggest some solution so that the ambiguity between similar sounding words may be resolved. Also please suggest the complete implementation of the training of the acoustic model. Thanks.